# A veces un enlace no responde ¿es normal?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en localhost con xampp y bueno, tengo una paginación creada con php. A veces no reacciona incluso haciendo click varias veces en cualquiera de los enlaces de la paginación, pero finalmente acaba respondiendo. Uso xampp 3.2.2 y win 10

¿Es normal o es algún error de código?

Os dejo el código php por si acaso

```html
<?php $numero_paginas = numero_paginas($blog_config['post_por_pagina'], $conexion); ?>

<section class="paginacion">
    <ul>
        <?php if(pagina_actual() === 1): ?>
            <li class="disabled"><a>&laquo;</a></li>
        <?php else: ?> 
            <li><a href="index.php?p=<?php echo pagina_actual() - 1; ?>">&laquo;</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $numero_paginas; $i++): ?>
            <?php if(pagina_actual() === $i): ?>
                <li class="actual"><a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?> 
        
        
        <?php if(pagina_actual() === $numero_paginas): ?>
            <li class="disabled"><a>&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=<?php echo pagina_actual() + 1; ?>">&raquo;</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: y cual es el enlace que no funciona?

Comment: Hola Shadow,
Gracias por tu respuesta. Acabo de editar la pregunta a ver si se entiende mejor

:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

No tienes necesidad de implementar una constante mezcla de código PHP/HTML. Buscar un error en tu código sería como buscar una aguja en un pajar.

Propongo que lo cambies por un estilo más claro, que consiste en quedarte dentro de un bloque entero PHP e ir concatenando allí los valores a una variable (`$html`)  y al final imprimir esa variable.

También, he usado operadores ternarios para asignar los valores, en vez de `if  ... then ...` Así ahorramos varias líneas de más. Estos operadores son relativamente nuevos, conviene descubrirlos y usarlos en comparaciones como las que se hacen en tu código, o incluso en otras más complejas. Si no te sientes cómodo con ellos, puedes sustituirlos por los tradicionales `if`.

Así el código debería funcionar:

```
$numero_paginas = numero_paginas($blog_config['post_por_pagina'], $conexion);
$page=pagina_actual(); 
$html="";
$html.="<section class=\"paginacion\">";
    $html.="<ul>";
        $li=( $page === 1 ) ? 
            "<li class=\"disabled\"><a>&laquo;</a></li>" :
            "<li><a href=\"index.php?p=".($page-1)."\">&laquo;</a></li>";
        $html.=$li;         
        for($i = 1; $i <= $numero_paginas; $i++) {
            $li=( $page === $i ) ?
                "<li class=\"actual\"><a href=\"index.php?p=$i\">$i</a></li>" :
                "<li><a href=\"index.php?p=$i\">$i</a></li>";                
            $html.=$li;    
        }

        $li=( $page === $numero_paginas ) ? 
            "<li class=\"disabled\">&raquo;</li>" :
            "<li><a href=\"index.php?p=".($page-1)."\">&raquo;</a></li>";
        $html.=$li;    
    $html.="</ul>";
$html.="</section>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @A. Cedano. La verdad es que me ha encantado el estilo de escritura, voy a estudiarlo para intentar adaptarlo de ese modo siempre que escriba.

La verdad es que el problema sigue existiendo. Es raro, porque a veces espero un rato y los enlaces de paginación me funcionan a la primera, otras veces no. Pero cuando lo hago recién cargado la pág no funcionan nunca, como si tuviese que esperar un poco

Muchas Gracias

Comment: @AlvaroTorres ese comportamiento puede deberse a otro factor, como por ejemplo la llamada a otras funciones o la carga de algunos archivos en el encabezado de la página... O a problemas de lentitud en el servidor.

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta dónde estaba el error...   el enlace solo funcionaba en el nº ya que las etiquetas <a> estaban al interior de <li>   jajajaja   Bueno, muchas gracias por tu ayuda    :D

Comment: Claro, solo es parte del enlace lo que esté dentro de `<a></a>`, @AlvaroTorres

Comment: Sí sí, ha sido un error muy absurdo. Ya no sabía dónde buscar. Pero es que a veces el error más simple es el peor...  :D Gracias por tu paciencia :D

Comment: @AlvaroTorres Pero me parece que te puse bien las etiquetas `<a><\a>` en la respuesta. Había un caso que no tenía `href` dentro, por lo que interprété que en ese caso no sería un enlace y le quité la etiqueta (es el penúltimo `li` que aparece en el código).

Comment: El error era que las etiquetas estaban de esta forma: [<li><a>EJEMPLO</a></li>] en lugar de: [<a><li>EJEMPLO</li></a>]. Pero no te preocupes, lo pregunté como un error de php cuando en realidad era un error de html. Además te agradezco muchísimo que me hayas mostrado esa forma de escritura para meter todo el html en una variable (ej. $html)  :D

Comment: @AlvaroTorres realmente no es un error, de hecho, es así como deberían ir. Hice pruebas con el código así y funcionaba. Si metes el li dentro de a te incluirá la viñeta del li en el enlace, lo cual es feo y además incorrecto, un elemento a no debería contener un elemento li, sino al revés.

Comment: @ A. Cedeano 
Perdona, tienes toda la razón.  En realidad el error estaba en el css. El tamaño de la caja (padding) se lo puse a <li> y entonces el enlace solo era el nª1 en este ejemplo  [<li><a>1</a></li>] y claro, yo quería que la caja completa fuese un enlace.

Ahora lo he solucionado poniendo la clase a <a>

:D